# How do I detect if there's a new line then ignore it (fgets)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char buf[100];
    char *pos;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
        if ((pos=strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);

    }

}
```

Consider I have a file like below

```
a

b

c
```

How do I detect if there's a new line and ignore it then continue the while loop. For example,

```
$ gcc -Wall above.c
$ ./a.out file
a
b
c
```

As you can see it ignored the new lines.

Comment: Use [`getline`](http://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112), `fgets` is not suitable for this.

Comment: `if(buf[0]) { printf("%s\n", buf); }`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I just put that before the first if

Comment: You should replace `printf("%s\n", buf);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a newline in the input, `fgets()` stops and includes it in the buffer. You don't need to search for it with `strchr()` as it will always be at `strlen() - 1` if present. Similarly, an empty line would mean that position `0` is a `\n`, in which case you could skip it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char buf[100];
    size_t len;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
        if (buf[(len = strlen(buf)) - 1] == '\n')
            buf[len - 1] = 0;
        if (len > 1)
            printf("%s\n", buf);

    }

}
```

Comment: Would there be a difference if you used buf[0] instead of strlen - 1?

Comment: @et In the case of the lines that are more than an newline, yes.